# Why does using admin-ajax.php result in 20 GET requests all with status 200?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a private front-end dashboard that allows a user to manage their client information, documents, etc - essentially a CRM. On one particular page, the clients are all loaded onto the page on load, and then each client has additional information that is loaded via ajax to ensure I am not bogging the website down.

Now it all works just fine, but as the subject line mentions, I get 20 calls to admin-ajax.php when the function runs, and all return successfully. So I'd like to get this figured out while I am in development rather than it becoming a resource issue later on.

I am using the below function to handle the AJAX request, the scripts.js file below contains the script I've included lower down. Depending on which tab is clicked, I then load a specific template:

```
//prep the JS + Ajax
function cyber_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('cyber_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    wp_localize_script('cyber_script', 'cyberAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cyber_load_scripts');

function ajax_load_tabs() {

$tab_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$user_id = $_REQUEST['userid'];

if (str_contains($tab_id,'#onboarding')) {
    get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'onboarding', array (
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    ));
}

elseif (str_contains($tab_id,'#tasks')) {
    get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'tasks', array (
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    ));
}

elseif (str_contains($tab_id,'#incidents')) {
    get_template_part( '/page-templates/dashboard/broker-dashboard', 'incidents', array (
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    ));
}
                                                                    
die();

}
    
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_load_tabs', 'ajax_load_tabs');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_load_tabs', 'ajax_load_tabs');
```

And the script that initializes the ajax call when the client clicks on the tab. I skip the first tab as that is loaded with the page. I then pass the tab ID and the user ID to the AJAX request:

```
    $( ".tabContent" ).each(function(index) {
        $('.profileTabs ul li a').click(function(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            
            //The first tab (overview) loads with the page
            if($(this).text().match('Overview')) {
                return false;
            }
            
            else {
                var tab_id = $(this).attr('href'); 
                var userid = $(this).attr('data-user');
    
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: cyberAjax.ajaxurl,
                    data: ({ 
                        action: 'ajax_load_tabs',
                        id: tab_id,
                        userid: userid,
                    }),
                    
                    success: function(data){
                              $(tab_id).html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data)  
                    {  
                    //alert("Error!");
                    console.log("Error!");
                    return false;
                    }  
    
                }); 
            }    
        });
```

Any ideas how I can make this call only once as intended? See below screen shot for reference:

[image: View of the XHR requests in the developers Network tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but from what I can tell from the code, it looks like you're binding the click listener to all the links, once for each tab.

You've got

```
$( ".tabContent" ).each(function(index) {
```

which will iterate once for each item with class `tabContent` and for each one of those, you're calling

```
$('.profileTabs ul li a').click(function(e) {
```

which will bind a click listener for every `.profileTabs ul li a` on the page, not just the ones inside the tabContent container you're looping over which is what I'm assuming you were trying to do.

If you don't actually care about which `tabContent` container you're in (which seems to be the case since you're not doing anything other than just immediately binding the click listener), I'd suggest something the outer .each i.e.

```js
$('.profileTabs ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //The first tab (overview) loads with the page
    if($(this).text().match('Overview')) {
        return false;
    }
    
    else {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('href'); 
        var userid = $(this).attr('data-user');

        $.ajax({ 
            url: cyberAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: ({ 
                action: 'ajax_load_tabs',
                id: tab_id,
                userid: userid,
            }),
            
            success: function(data){
                        $(tab_id).html(data);
            },
            error: function(data)  
            {  
            //alert("Error!");
            console.log("Error!");
            return false;
            }  

        }); 
    }    
});
```

If you need/want to only bind it to links that match the selector within the `tabContent` elements, just change the selector to include the tabContent class too i.e. `$('.tabContent .profileTabs ul li a').click(function(e) {...`